# How do I install a Realtek Wireless-N USB Adapter on my Linux OS laptop

Tags: wireless, usb, adapter

I just bought a Realtek wireless-n usb adapter and I'm having problems installing it to my Linux OS laptop. It will not run the setup.exe. It is a Ultra-Mini USB Wireless Lan 802.11N Adapter - 1T1R and I bought it at monoprice.com. Where can I go to and download the proper driver?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Note that Ubuntu doesn't run .exe files (well any Linux OS for that matter!). .exe files run only on Windows OS. So this means you are trying to install a driver, that is meant for Windows OS instead of the one for Linux,  for your wireless adapter. So find a Linux driver for your wireless adapter and it should work fine.

Comment: Also from the next time you ask a question please remember to mention which version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: We can't answer this without your exact realtek model. What is the output of `lspci -nn | grep Network`? Please [edit] it into your question. Thanks!

Comment: It's a USB model, not a PCI one. I filtered the non-USB ones in my answer.

Comment: @pilona Ah, you're right! I missed that in the title. I guess it isn't unclear then :)

Answer (score 3):

You likely don't need to install anything. The drivers for many of the Realtek wireless adapters are already in-tree. I have an 8192CU myself.

At least the following RT chipsets are supported:

- 8192CU
- 8188CU
- 8712
- 8188EU
- 8821 (USB?)

As for ancially matters:

- It's **NOT** "Linux OS", just Linux to be generic, or Ubuntu.
- You can't run Windows PE executables (`.exe`) under Linux. They're *different*. Linux uses ELF , and regardless the libraries `seutp.exe` is linked against are neither present nor of the appropriate format. You could use Wine to try and run the program but that is obviously futile here. This is a different OS.
- Vendor-provided drivers are often outdated. In Linux, be wary of anything not in-tree, save a few.
- If the vendor provided additional userspace to manage your wireless device, it's just reinventing and reimplementing the wheel. There's already a plethora of generic better-developed Linux-target programs for managing wireless adapters.