# How Can I Enable a Realtek USB Antenna?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, realtek

I have a USB antenna that I got [here on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B018TX8IDA), and unlike in [How do I install a Realtek Wireless-N USB Adapter on my Linux OS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475068/how-do-i-install-a-realtek-wireless-n-usb-adapter-on-my-linux-os-laptop) it doesn't appear  that the driver is in the driver tree. Either that or I haven't figured out how to enable the antenna. I'm using a laptop, which has an integrated Wi-Fi connector, but I wanted a better external one. I'm not exactly sure how this works with the wi-fi button on the laptop. I tried installing the default driver, but the installation fails stating that the kernel version isn't supported (It only works on version 3.14), but my Ubuntu version is 16.04, running the default kernel `4.4.0-79-generic`, with the `KDE` environment. How can I enable the USB antenna?

Edit 0: Output of `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05c8:036e Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) Webcam
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 04f9:0278 Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 1a40:0201 Terminus Technology Inc. FE 2.1 7-port Hub
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 0c45:7b05 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Edit 1: After multiple executions of `lsusb` with the antenna in and out of the hub I can confirm that `Bus 002 Device 012: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp` is the device.

Edit 2: According to Someone in the Amazon Questions, the chipset used is `Realtek RTL8811AU Wireless LAN 802.11ac USB 2.0 Network Adapter`

Edit 3: Output of `ifconfig`

```
$ ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:1d:48:fa:67:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.1.19  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fddf:8e79:2441:c273/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1035634 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:454085 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1479578464 (1.4 GB)  TX bytes:48852719 (48.8 MB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:10250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10250 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:927499 (927.4 KB)  TX bytes:927499 (927.4 KB)
```

Edit 4: System Settings Network Tab
[image: Network Tab]

Edit 5:

```
# lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [103c:197d]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Comment: Please plug it in and then run the following command and then please post the output, thanks: `lsusb`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Reboot.

We will also need to blacklist your internal device. First, let's identify it:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
```

To blacklist the driver for the internal device, open the terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8188ee"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r rtl8188ee
exit
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Hmm, the internal card was disabled, but the new one is still offline. It doesn't appear in the System Settings -> Connections list either. I verified that the USB antenna works by using it on a windows system, so at least I know it's not dead.

Comment: Is the driver loaded? `lsmod | grep 8812` Is it hard blocked? `rfkill list all`

Comment: First command gave no output. Second one gave this:  `0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
`

Comment: Please include the rfkill listing and a reference to this question and start a new question as you have what appears to be a new problem. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: What do you think I should put as the title of the new question then? It would seem to be a duplicate in my mind.

Comment: Although Driver Installed, Wireless Does Not Appear.

Comment: Posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/932092/wireless-antenna-does-not-appear-despite-its-driver-being-installed

Comment: Just curious, how would I unblacklist the internal wi-fi driver?

Comment: I suggest: `sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and remove the line you added above; namely `blacklist rtl8188ee` Save, close, reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Bought this Honey USB 600 Mbps WiFi antenna off Amazon for less than $10 since it claimed it works with Linux.  It does, but not plug and play like some of the other more popular adapters.  I tried the above methods for Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.2 Bionic Beaver) and they failed; however, they did help me get to this point. I did find a method that works.  Just follow the directions (4 steps) on the image in this link ----> [Realtek 8812 Honey USB wireless adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzsPk.png) then, Reboot.

If this helps you like it did me, give it a thumbs up!