# Wireless antenna does not appear despite its driver being installed

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, kubuntu, 17.04

I have an external USB antenna whose driver was installed, yet does not appear in System Settings/Connections in Kubuntu 17.04. More information can be found in the original question about this issue ([How Can I Enable a Realtek USB Antenna?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923222/how-can-i-enable-a-realtek-usb-antenna)).

Output of `lsmod | grep 8812` & `rfkill list all`

```
$ lsmod | grep 8812
$ rfkill list all
$: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Output of `sudo dkms status`:

```
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-381, 381.22, 4.10.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-381, 381.22, 4.10.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.10.0-24-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.10.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Outpus of `modinfo 8812au | grep A811`:

```
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Output of `lsmod | grep 8812`:

```
Nothing Displayed
```

Output of `lsmod | grep 8812`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -i -e rtl -e 8812`:

```
[22538.388812] usb 2-14: Device not responding to setup address.
[65970.179027] 8812au: version magic '4.10.0-24-generic SMP mod_unload ' should be '4.10.0-26-generic SMP mod_unload '
```

Output of `iwconfig` & `dmesg | grep 8812`:

```
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ iwconfig
eno1      no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
sarah@ConvergentRefuge:~$ dmesg | grep 8812
[ 2028.287249] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
[ 2028.287338] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
[ 2033.979052] audit: type=1400 audit(1499387534.619:709): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7" pid=8812 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2623.150998] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388123.752:1185): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7-1000" pid=9914 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2623.170431] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388123.772:1186): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7-1000" pid=9915 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2623.252008] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388123.856:1187): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7" pid=9916 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2623.295266] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388123.900:1188): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7" pid=9917 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2628.207767] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388128.812:1189): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7-1000" pid=9918 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2628.252204] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388128.856:1190): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7-1000" pid=9919 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2628.302456] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388128.904:1191): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7" pid=9920 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
[ 2628.341144] audit: type=1400 audit(1499388128.944:1192): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="webbrowser-app" name="/dev/shm/lttng-ust-wait-7" pid=9921 comm="QQmlThread-ust" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, verify that the module installed correctly:

```
sudo dkms status
```

We hope we see:

```
rtl8812AU, 5, 4.10.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Or similar.

Verify that the installed module covers your device, which is:

```
ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

Run, in the terminal:

```
modinfo 8812au | grep A811
```

We hope we see:

```
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Note that the second alias, 0BDA with A811 covers your device.

Is the module loaded?

```
lsmod | grep 8812
```

If not, load it:

```
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

Are there any errors or warnings you can post? Or does the wireless come to life? If not, check the log for informative messages:

```
dmesg | grep -i -e rtl -e 8812
```

**EDIT**: We see the problem here:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error

I suggest that you correct it with:

```
 sudo apt-get purge rtl8812au-dkms 
 sudo apt-get install rtl8812au-dkms
 sudo modprobe 8812au
```

If there are errors or warnings, please post them.

**EDIT2**: I suggest that we try another approach.

```
sudo apt-get purge rtl8812au-dkms 
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8812AU.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8812AU
sudo dkms install rtl8812AU/5
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I posted the outputs of the commands

Comment: Please see my edit in a few minutes.

Comment: Uninstall & reinstall went seamlessly, but still no activity on either system settings/connections or any activity on the actual USB antenna LED. Perhaps this is using the wrong driver? There were no warnings or errors in uninstall/reinstall. Also, the modprobe command executed without returning any text.

Comment: May we see: `iwconfig` and also: `dmesg | grep 8812`

Comment: I posted the output of those two commands

Comment: I will change my answer. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Hmm, now it works. Why did it only work from git though?

Comment: It's a later version and covers your usb,id. The previous did not and I didn't see it clearly. Glad ir's working.

Comment: I just upgraded to 17.10 and now I'm getting an error message when I try to follow the instructions again. Should I post it to a new question?

Comment: Yes, please post a new question. It will probably help a lot of searchers.

Comment: Posted to: https://askubuntu.com/questions/970283/ubuntu-17-10-drivers-not-found-working-properly

Comment: Just a minor note, I've switched my computer downstairs to Kubuntu 18.04 and tried `sudo dkms install rtl8812AU/5` and got `Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-22-generic (x86_64)`

Comment: Please see my comment at your other question.

Answer (score 0):

After 8 hours of trying finally these steps worked for me:

1. first I turned the secure boot off inside the BIOS (this step was the key solution)
   Because of this change I was able to  run :
   $ modprobe 8812au
   Otherwise I got the permission denied response
2. I used this repo to install the driver:
   [aircrack-ng/rtl8812au](https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au/)

3. reboot
4. if it is necessary:

   $ modprobe 8812au

or

```
$ sudo modprobe 8812au
```

or

```
$ modprobe --force 8812au
```

or

```
$ sudo modprobe --force 8812au
```

worked for me

device: alfa awus036ach USB wireless adapter

os: ubuntu 20.04 LTS