# 19.04 - rtl8812au-dkms installed but not appearing as module

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

Adding additional info as suggested by chili555 in 
[Wireless antenna does not appear despite its driver being installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932092/wireless-antenna-does-not-appear-despite-its-driver-being-installed).

I installed the rtl8812au driver via apt and installation seems to be successful. The device is a USB-wifi dongle that is recognized by lsusb

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
```

But not by iwconfig.

DKMS sees the driver.

```
 $ dkms status | grep rtl
   rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.0.0-13-generic, x86_64: installed
   rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.0.0-15-generic, x86_64: installed
```

But the driver does not appear as a module :

```
  lsmod | grep rtl
  btrtl                  20480  1 btusb
  bluetooth             557056  73 
  btrtl,hidp,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
```

Adding additional info as suggested by chili555

```
  modinfo 8812au | grep A811
  alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

***Note that this output does not include Chilli's hoped for: ***

```
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

But I am not sure why we should be expecting that value.

```
 dmesg | grep l8812
```

returns empty

Checking journalctl

```
 journalctl | grep 8812
 TTY=pts/9 ; PWD=/hd2/projects ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe rtl8812au
 TTY=pts/9 ; PWD=/hd2/projects ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe rtl8812au-dkms
 TTY=pts/9 ; PWD=/hd2/projects ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe rtl8812
 TTY=pts/9 ; PWD=/hd2/projects ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/modprobe -r rtl8812au
```

Comment: @chili555 Thanks chili, although the question is the same and the diagnostics apply, I do not have the same problem. There is no module format error. I wonder about the missing alias -- as noted in the edited question. Is that meaningful? What could be the issue here?

Comment: Try using https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: @Jeremy31 Worked. Post as answer.

Comment: The correct and exact alias *must* be in the driver or it does not claim and drive the device. Glad it's working.